# How can I set the value of a text box in a record set to a hyperlink address?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am trying to loop through a record set and set the value returned for txtC1 to a hyperlink address for each record.

Here is the code I have come up with so far:

```
sqlqry = "Select A1, B1, C1 From Table"

Me.Form1.Form.txtC1.SetFocus
i = 0
rs.Open sqlqry, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
With rs
Do
    Do Until rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
        If rs.EOF Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Me.Form1.Form.txtC1.HyperlinkAddress = Me.Form1.Form.txtC1.Text
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
```

I'm getting the error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

On the line

```
Me.Form1.Form.txtC1.HyperlinkAddress = Me.Form1.Form.txtC1.Text
```

Perhaps a different approach would be better?

EDIT:

After messing with it some more, I've been able to set the hyperlink for all records by using  a label and hidden text box. However, instead of changing the hyperlink target to the value of the hidden text box for each iteration of the loop, it is setting each link to the value of the first text box.

I am trying to implement a for each loop to change the link for each record by using the ADO Field object, but I'm not sure how to tell it what field to look at. Here is the new code

```
i = 0
rs.Open sqlqry, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
With rs
Do
    Do Until rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
    hLink = Me.Form1.Form.txtC1.Value
        If rs.EOF Then
            Exit Do
        End If
   Me.Form1.Form.lbl.HyperlinkAddress = hLink
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
```

Comment: Doesn't matter how many records there are, there is only the one label control. All records will display the same setting. If textbox has value, why do you need label to reflect the same text? Why is textbox hidden? What are you really trying to accomplish? Show sample data and desired result.

Comment: Don't use Text property to grab value of textbox control. Use Value and since it is default property of data controls, don't even have to reference it. Also, iterating a normal recordset object does not iterate controls or records on form.

Comment: Even though the text box is a filepath string, I can't make it a clickable link because I am already using the  control source to set the value of the box... That's why I am setting the label equal to the hidden text box and making that my clickable hyperlink. Each textbox shows a filepath string that is unique for that record, so I am trying to make the label take the user to the filepath destination.

Comment: Use Current event to set property, don't loop through a recordset. Regardless,  aIl records will show same setting on label. Or use another textbox with expression.

Answer (score 1):

An Access hyperlink is composed of 3 parts separated by # character (http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html). If a text field has a string that meets one of the second part structures, such as a filepath or URL string, a textbox can be a clickable hyperlink with IsHyperlink property set to Yes and expression in ControlSource:

`="Click to Open File#" & Me!fieldname & "#"`

Or use VBA to execute FollowHyperlink method.